# Histogram Graph in ModelSim Simulator

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim

I have a Memory (Register Bank), this bank has 255 registers that each register contains a 16 bit number, type of registers is STD_LOGIC_VECTOR but there is no problem if I should convert them to Integer

I want to show an Histogram Graph in simulation wave window

In fact, I want to show a 2 axis graph with 0..255 as X and the 16 bit number (as Integer) as Y

Is it possible ? how ?

If it is not possible, what is your suggestion to show the Histogram graph ?

thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the only graphing that Modelsim can do internally is to show the value of a multi-bit bus as an "analog" value. Therefore, one thing you could do is create a module for your testbench that reads out the histogram memory sequentially (either periodically or based on a trigger generated elsewhere in the testbench) and then display the output bus as a waveform.

The alternative would be to write the histogram data to an external file as it is created. An external script (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.) that runs in parallel with your simulation would monitor that file for updates and then forward the data to something like Gnuplot to display it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to show an histogram on Modelsim. There is an additional problem, and that is that if that histogram existed, it would be time dependent.

You can export the memory contents (File -> Export -> Memory Data) at a specific time of the simulation and process the data with exteral SW like Excel to produce the histogram.